# Capture real-time screen video from iPhone and iPad including audio and post to YouTube, Facebook, etc

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es, youtube, capture

Does anyone have pointers to some working code or techniques for capturing the full-screen real-time OpenGL graphics on the iPhone and iPad, combine it with the audio coming out of the device, and compile it into a video to post online?

For example, apps such as "Talking Tomcat" do this. I'm using Cocos2D, but a solution from any framework is welcome, ideally using up-to-date APIs. It seems like this should be a solved problem given how useful and pervasive such a function is. However, all the postings I have found on this topic are out of date or incomplete.

One of the better sources of information I've found so far is here: http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2011/04/12/voices-that-matter-iphone-spring-2011/

Answer (score 7):

There's an updated version of the above-mentioned [ScreenCaptureView](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) class available that has video-recording support built-in (see link).  It hasn't been tested with an OpenGL subview, but assuming that it works you might be able to modify it slightly to include audio and then you'd be set.

Edit - Working link here:  https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view

Comment: This link no longer works. Microsoft got No-IP [shut down](http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/archive/2014/06/30/microsoft-takes-on-global-cybercrime-epidemic-in-tenth-malware-disruption.aspx) due to their use by malware.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Well that's unfortunate, and disruptive.  Does Microsoft intend to take down all DDNS services then?  And since when did they become the Internet police?  Regardless; the updated code from the link is also available on [github](https://github.com/adam-roth/screen-cap-view).

Answer (score 5):

I found this simple [ScreenCaptureView](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/541) class that might help. It saves the contents of a UIView to a UIImage. The author suggests you can save a video of the app in use by passing the frames through [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: The first link no longer works. Microsoft got No-IP [shut down](http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/archive/2014/06/30/microsoft-takes-on-global-cybercrime-epidemic-in-tenth-malware-disruption.aspx) due to their use by malware.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but if someone comes across the same problem.

There are ready-made solutions / services for doing this so if you're not looking to re-invent the wheel, you can try for example Everyplay (https://everyplay.com/about) which does exactly that.

Check out the Cocos2d integration docs here: https://developers.everyplay.com/doc/Everyplay-integration-to-Cocos2d-game

Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes Everyplay. We try to solve the exact problem that the original question poses.

Answer (score 2):

you can try Kamcord, which is a SDK for record your app video.

Comment: Looks promising and has a built in network for sharing videos with others... https://www.kamcord.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that saving the contents of the UIView does not capture any other views or components that are not subviews of that component. For instance you would not capture keyboards, popovers or dialogs.